# What does noncomputable really mean?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, computability, computational-mathematics

I believe I understand the definition of a noncomputable problem from an introductory computer science class, but I don't understand what it *really* means.

One of my hypothesis was that a noncomputable problem really means that you would need an increasing program size to compute, say, all instances of the problem up to size n in time at most finite T. Since the definition of TM requires finite program size, this means that the problem is noncomputable. Is there a theorem along those lines?

Do we have orders of growth for programs generating instances up to size n of problems? (ie for noncomputable it seems to me that it would be anything above constant)

This seems to suggest further computability classes, like c(computable), ln(n), n, exp(n),...

Am I making any sense here?

Comment: No. For example, there may be a noncomputable problem with only one instance of a fixed size. What you describe is related to Kolmogorov complexity.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan From the little I know about Kolmogorov complexity, that makes sense. I'm sorry if this was a senseless question, I was curious on the actual meaning of being non computable, because the definition didn't give me too much intuition about it. So reformulating my question, consider problems with varying instance sizes. Is the following true: "The Kolmogorov complexity of the ordered set of output bits (a string) is finite"  iff "The problem is computable"?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Only one instance of a fixed size?  But then surely there is an algorithm that produces the answer (as long as it exists, even if we don't happen to know what it is).

Comment: @Robert: suppose, for example, that the instance for size $n$ is "determine whether or not the Turing machine of index $n$ halts."

Answer (score 1):

Any particular instance of the problem has an answer (even if we don't happen to know it).  The same for any finite collection of instances.  If you're using a finite alphabet, there are only finitely many instances up to size $n$, and so there's certainly a "lookup table" style program that computes the answers to all these.  So saying there's a program that solves all instances up to size $n$ in finite time isn't really saying anything useful.

EDIT: Similarly, from the fact that there are only finitely many programs of a given size, you can see that if for every $n$ there is a program of size $\le N$ that solves all instances of size $\le n$, there must be a program of size $\le N$ that solves all instances.

Comment: So perhaps there is a way to quantify how far can we get from the lookup table approach as a measure of hardness? (ie lookup tables grow exponentially with input bits, so the size of the program would be exp(n), which should be as hard as possible)

Comment: Your EDIT is very interesting. Thanks!